# how to calculate Weighted Averaging and distances in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a set of data (100*3) which are (x,y,z). I need to calculate the 2nd order polynomial interpolation(it have been done) and weighted averaging.
I have the below code now. I am now trying to calculate weighted averaging with the attached formulas [enter image description here][1]. I need to first find out all the distance(d) between those 100 data and (50,50), then find the 5 nearest points. Secondly, calculate weighting(w). finally, calculate the Z. How can I calculate those data in Octave? Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMbP6.png

````
pkg load io
data = xlsread('data.xlsx');

## categorize the data
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);
z = data(:,3);

## 2nd order polynomial interpolation
## Find polynomial coefficient

A = [ones(size(data,1),1) x y x.*y x.^2 y.^2];
a = pinv(A)*z;

## interpolation
grid_x = [0:2:100]';
grid_y = grid_x;
grid_z = zeros(size(grid_x,1), size(grid_x,1));

for i1 = 1:size(grid_x,1)
  for i2 = 1:size(grid_y, 1)
    A = [1 grid_x(i1) grid_y(i2) grid_x(i1).*grid_y(i2) grid_x(i1).^2 grid_y(i2).^2];
    grid_z(i1, i2) = A*a;
  endfor
end ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could use distance formula d2=(Xi-2)2+(Yi-2)2 to find distance where X and Y are the coordinate of the new interpolated point; and xi and yi are the
coordinate of the i, and then select the 5 nearest point. For Weight averaging, you could use w=1/d2.